# angularjs: Sum two inputs and display in third input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need two input field's value to be added and displayed in the third input field. It is indeed simple to have input type as number but unfortunately this doesnot work in IE. it works just fine in chrome. Could you please help me on how to do it in IE so that it would support both.

```
<tr>
                                    <th>Business</th>
                                    <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input1"/></th>
                                    <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input2"/></th>
                                    <th style="background-color:beige"><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" value="{{input1+input2}}" readonly /></th>
                                    <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input3"/></th>
                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach `ng-value="input1+input2"` will work in `IE11`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope){})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
<table data-ng-controller="AppController">
  <tr>
     <th>Business</th>
     <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input1"/></th>
     <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input2"/></th>
     <th style="background-color:beige"><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-value="input1+input2" readonly /></th>
     <th><input type="number" class="col-sm-12" ng-model="input3"/></th>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```